# RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from

Tags: python

ran into an error when using Google collab Disco Diffusion. I don't understand what the issue is very well because obviously I do have an Nvidia graphics card and am running nvidia drivers, and so I don't understand why the collab isn't seeing it.

I tried downloading two different drivers from the links provided, and it didn't solve the issue.

When providing a solution, please assume that I'm a complete noob that a needs a detailed breakdown of what to do.

Looking up the issue didn't particularly help either, because answers are rather unclear and don't seem to correspond to my specific scenario.